# Not getting an the image rendition option when using SP Rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I been trying to make out the URL in order to make a REST call which will fetch an image rendition from SP and then grab its value in order to convert it to base 64.  I have been playing with the URL.  I am working with a picture library.  I am using the following URL's but I have not had any success.  I have been crawling the web and have not seen any exmples

```
 var url1 = "https://tentnat.sharepoint.com/sites/*site*/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('*relativeUrl*')/Pictures?select=RenditionID&$ Filter=RenditionID eq 1"; << get 404

 var url2 = "https://tentnat.sharepoint.com/sites/*site*/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('*relativeUrl*?RenditionID=1 '); << get 404

 var url3 = "https://tentnat.sharepoint.com/sites/*site*/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('*relativeUrl*')/?RenditionID=1/$value"; << get 404

 var url4 = "https://tentnat.sharepoint.com/sites/*site*/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('*relativeUrl*')/$value"; << this is valid and does get me the image *200*
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Basically opened an SP session with IE and used this authenticated sessions to build out my rendition URL
    function StartSPSession() {
    //this will just open a window that has the Sp site Url,
    // it will authenticate in order to grab image renditions.
    // quick fix to implement renditions
    var sharepointSite = window.open("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ContentCenter", '_blank', 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=5, height=5, visible=none', '');
    setTimeout(function () { sharepointSite.close(); }, 8000);
};

Comment: have you found a way to get this to work through Rest api ? @sjkp

Comment: I have not - which is why I asked. But opening a browser is not an option for me as I only have sharepoint app credentials. But I guess my app will then have to resize the images. Sucks, but seems like the REST API is also incomplete in this area.